# How can we prove a specific isomorphism between graded Lie algebra and graded universal enveloping algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\gr{gr}$Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over field of characteristic different from $2$, and let $L_n$ be its descending central series. Therefore, we consider the associated graded Lie algebra $\gr L =\bigoplus_{n}\frac{L_n}{L_{n+1}}$. Moreover,  let consider the universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$ which is graded by the augmentation ideal denoted by $I$, that is, $\gr U(L)=\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \gr^{n} U(L)$, where $\gr^{n}U(L)=I^n/I^{n+1}$. How can we show that $I^2/I^{3} \cong L_2/L_3 \otimes S_{2}(L/L_{2})$, where $S_{2}(L/L_{2})$ is the symmetric algebra of $\gr^{2} L$.